# How to delete an empty column passed through a Google table to an array in python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm new to python. Now I'm trying to work with Google tables

I need help

Sometimes there may be 2 columns with the same names in the table, and one of them will always be empty. And in such cases, python sees an empty column. I need to implement code that would delete it in such cases and read another non-empty column. But at the same time, this should not be done through pandas. All data is stored in an array

That is my code

```
    def GetVariableType(self, lineid): 

       

        if self.googleObject.VariableType_orderid!= None:

            if len(self.googleObject.sheet[lineid])>self.googleObject.VariableType_orderid:

                return self.IsNull(self.googleObject.sheet[lineid][self.googleObject.VariableType_orderid])

            

            else:

                return None

        else:

 

            return None
```

Comment: are you aware that google-sheets works natively with javascript...  [example video](https://youtube.com/live/lKEcJ1dd564?feature=share)